# Complex Command DataBinding between nested UserControls in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, wpf-controls

I have a UserControl called **PAInstructionsControl** inside my **TestAdmin** Class Library.

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestAdmin.Controls.PAInstructionsControl">
        <Button Command="{Binding ???}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding ???}"/>
</UserControl>
```

In the consumers of this UserControl: I need a ViewModel used as the Button's Command Binding and a different ViewModel for its CommandParameter but I'm not sure how to do this.

In my **WMT** Class Library I have a **WmtPAInstructionsView** UserControl that consumes the **PAInstructionsControl**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WMT.View.WmtPAInstructionsView"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:TestAdmin.Controls;assembly=TestAdmin">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="WMT PA Instructions View"
                   Margin="10"/>

        <controls:PAInstructionsControl />

    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

The **WmtPAInstructionsView** is nested inside a **WMT.WmtMainWindow** UserControl
[image: WMT]

*If the Button was simply inside the **WmtPAInstructionsView** UserControl*, then I would need these ViewModel bindings :

```
<Button 
    Command="{Binding DataContext.DisplayNextIndexedViewCommand, RelativeSource=
                {RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:WmtMainWindow}}, Mode=OneWay}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
```

So the command would bind to a command within the **WmtMainWindow**'s DataContext.  The CommandParameter would be the **WmtPAInstructionView**'s DataContext which is the **WmtPAInstructionsViewModel**

But I need the button in the **PAInstructionsControl** so it can be re-used elsewhere in my solution.  What would I use for the bindings of the Command and CommandParameter?  Do I need Dependency Properties?

---

*Hopefully the above information is all you need to help answer my question.  Here is more information if you need it:*

---

I also have a **MSVT** Class Library that has a **MsvtPAInstructionsView** UserControl that consumes the **PAInstructionsControl** in a similar way.

*If the Button was simply inside the  **MsvtPAInstructionsView** UserControl*, then I would need these ViewModel bindings :

```
<Button 
    Command="{Binding DataContext.DisplayNextIndexedViewCommand, RelativeSource=
                {RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MsvtMainWindow}}, Mode=OneWay}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
```

Both the **WMT** and **MSVT** Class Libraries reference the **TestAdmin** library.  **WMT** and **MVST** do NOT reference each other.

Here is the Main Application Window (WpfTestBase.MainWindow):

[image: Main Application Window]

Clicking on "New WMT Test" opens a new WpfTestBase.TestView Window.
This TestView Window has several nested user controls :
[image: WMT]

Here's the Visual Tree:

[image: Visual Tree]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "easy" (and sort of bad) solution would be to do this:

```
<Button 
    Command="{Binding DataContext.DisplayNextIndexedViewCommand, RelativeSource=
                {RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Mode=OneWay}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
```

This would work for *any* subclass of `Window`. While it does "solve" your problem, it makes a number of assumptions. The biggest is that you'd be assuming you'll always want your `Button` to bind to the parent `Window`, and that that `Window`'s `DataContext` will always have a property exactly named `DisplayNextIndexedViewCommand`.

---

A better solution would be to define a chain of `DependencyProperty`s in each of your `UserControl`s, where you would bind each child to its parent. This would give you total flexibility when consuming the controls.

Start with `PAInstructionsControl` and define a `DisplayNextIndexedViewCommand` `DependencyProperty`. You would then bind `Buton.Command` to that property like so:

```
<Button 
    Command="{Binding DisplayNextIndexedViewCommand, RelativeSource=
                {RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:PAInstructionsControl}}, Mode=OneWay}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
```

This brings you one level of nesting closer to the top. Next, also declare a `DisplayNextIndexedViewCommand` `DependencyProperty` in `WmtPAInstructionsView`. This lets you bind `PAInstructionsControl.DisplayNextIndexedViewCommand` to `WmtPAInstructionsView.DisplayNextIndexedViewCommand` like so:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WMT.View.WmtPAInstructionsView"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:TestAdmin.Controls;assembly=TestAdmin">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="WMT PA Instructions View"
                   Margin="10"/>

        <controls:PAInstructionsControl DisplayNextIndexedViewCommand="{Binding DisplayNextIndexedViewCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:WmtPAInstructionsView}}}"/>

    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Now, finally, you can bind `WmtPAInstructionsView.DisplayNextIndexedViewCommand` to the *actual* command, which you have living in your `Window`'s `DataContext`:

```
<local:WmtPAInstructionsView DisplayNextIndexedViewCommand="{Binding DataContext.DisplayNextIndexedViewCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:WmtMainWindow}}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

(Also, since `DataContext` is inherited, you might be able to leave out "`DataContext.`" and the whole `RelativeSource` from the `Binding`)

Comment: I believe there is a typo in your last line of code for the WmtMainWindow.  The DataContext is in the wrong place.  It should be:
`<local:WmtPAInstructionsView DisplayNextIndexedViewCommand="{Binding DataContext.DisplayNextIndexedViewCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:WmtMainWindow}}, Mode=OneWay}"/>`

Comment: @JohnnyHerms Correct. I've accepted the edit.